# How to purge Notepad from the Windows Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-explorer

I've installed *[insert favourite text editor here]* and associated it with all file extensions which by default open with notepad.exe. Still, there is a context menu entry `Edit` e.g. on `*.txt` files which still brings up Notepad.

How can I change this context menu entry to also open my editor instead of Notepad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places in the Windows registry that define context menu entries:

- File extension

  For `*.txt` files, the default value of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` points to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile`, which defines the context menu entries
- [Perceived type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144150.aspx)

  `*.txt` files have a perceived type `text` (see `PerceivedType` property in key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt`), and that type defines its context menu entries at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text`

If you also change the commands for the perceived type `text`, you should always get your favourite editor for all text files.